# TSP100 and reportviewer 10.0 A7

Tags: c#, rdlc, thermal-printer

I have an issue trying to print a report generated with MS Report Viewer 10.0 on a TSP100 thermal printer in A7 paper size.
Please, can anybody provide a code about it?

Comment: I have define in the report properties the A7 format size (74 mm x 105 mm) and when I print my retail, it is printed on the bottom of the paper and I also got and Empty paper at the end.

Comment: I would try to remove all margins and if it doesn't help, try to reduce paper size in report properties

Comment: Hello, I finally found the solution. The trick is to send raw data directly to the thermal printer by using a class provided by Microsoft and the ESC/POS language to format your data. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The trick is to send raw data directly to the thermal printer by using a [class](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) provided by Microsoft and the ESC/POS language specs of your thermal printer provider, to format your data.

The best way is to, ask to your thermal printer provider for sample code.
Thanks to all.